# Mapear etiqueta repetitiva XML en objeto Java

Tags: java, xml, java-8

Tengo el siguiente xml:

```
<mensajeWS>
    <respuestaGetCabecerasType>
        <cabeceras>
            <cabecera>
                <id>1234</id>
                <tipoMensaje>3</tipoMensaje>
                <datos>
                    <fechaEnvio>2023-12-13T00:05:00</fechaEnvio>
                    <fechaEnvio>2023-12-14T00:05:00</fechaEnvio>
                </datos>
            </cabecera>
        </cabeceras>
    </respuestaGetCabecerasType>
</mensajeWS>
```

Y quiero mapear sus datos en el siguiente objeto:

```
public class Cabecera implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -865317642824095952L;
    
    private int id;
    
    private int tipoMensaje;
    
    private DatosRecepcion datos;
```

Donde DatosRecepcion es una clase con la siguiente variable:

```
public class DatosRecepcion implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6703565058845907875L;
    
    private List<String> fechaEnvio;
```

Para mapear los datos del xml al objeto realizo lo siguiente:

```
List<Cabecera> listaCabeceras = new ArrayList<Cabecera>();
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml.toString())));
            
            System.out.println("Root element: " + document.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            
            NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("cabecera");
            for(int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(i);
                System.out.println("Current Element: " + nNode.getNodeName());
                
                Element element = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("id: " + element.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Tipo de mensaje: " + element.getElementsByTagName("tipoMensaje").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Fecha de Envio: " + element.getElementsByTagName("fechaEnvio").item(0).getTextContent());
                
                Cabecera cabecera = new Cabecera();
                cabecera.setId(Integer.parseInt(element.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent()));
                cabecera.setTipoMensaje(Integer.parseInt(element.getElementsByTagName("tipoMensaje").item(0).getTextContent()));
                
                listaCabeceras.add(cabecera);
                
            }
```

Me gustaría saber cómo mapear una etiqueta repetitiva como es fechaEnvio a mi Objeto Java. Utilizo la versión 8 de Java y no me dejan utilizar por el momento una superior

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

Comment: Pues... en vez de acceder a mano con el `item(0)` hardcodeado usa un bucle para leer todos los items de ese tag. Nunca vas a poder acceder a más de uno si en el código hardcodeas el acceso al 0 nada más.

Comment: @Benito-B alguna sugerencia? yo ahora no encuentro ninguna

Comment: ¿Has pensado en utilizar JAXB https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAXB?

Comment: El xml no será un fichero sino que es un string que devolverá un WS de Soap, ¿Puede valer?